# WebSocket connection automatically disconnects after around 30 seconds when accessing via Kubernetes Service IP

Tags: kubernetes, networking, websocket, service

I'm setting up a Kubernetes cluster using version v1.18 and I've encountered a strange issue. Everything works fine when I access the WebSocket service directly using the Pod IP. However, when I try to access the same WebSocket service using the Service IP, the connection always automatically disconnects after approximately 30 seconds.

Here are the steps I've tried so far:

Ensured the Service is correctly configured and properly associated with the backend Pod.
Checked the WebSocket server's configuration to ensure it can handle connection requests from the Service IP.
Verified network connectivity and firewall rules to ensure there are no restrictions on connections from the Service IP.
Verified the underlying network devices and configurations to ensure inter-node network connectivity.
My Kubernetes version is v1.18, and I'm considering upgrading to the latest version.
Additional information that might be helpful:

Kubernetes version: v1.18
Kubeproxy mode: iptables
I have also discovered that my Kubeproxy is using the iptables mode, which might have an impact on WebSocket connections. Under this mode, I suspect that there might be some iptables rules or configurations causing the connection to drop.

Regarding this issue, I would appreciate any advice or guidance on using Kubernetes Service to access WebSocket services specifically in the iptables mode. Are there any specific iptables configurations or rules that can help resolve this issue?

Thank you very much for your attention and support! Any suggestions on how to resolve this issue and any in-depth analysis of potential causes would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

I expect the behavior to be the same when accessing via the Service IP as it is with the Pod IP, meaning the connection should not automatically disconnect.

Comment: 1.18 is old. but beside that, you don't mention how many pods you are running and how you configured the service. Websocket requires some session affinity to avoid the connection being load balanced between pods. https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/networking/virtual-ips/#session-affinity

Comment: Sorry, it was my negligence. But in my cluster, the service only corresponds to a unique pod.

Comment: Another strange thing is that when there is only one worker node in my cluster, everything is normal. But when I have multiple worker nodes in my cluster, the above problem occurs